# How do I pass on checkbox id using v-on in Vue.js when checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, object, checkbox, vue.js, parameter-passing

this is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checklist-1-checkbox-1" v-on:click="addGreenClass(this)" name="checkbox1-1">
```

vue.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#admin-dashboard',
  methods: {
    addGreenClass(element) {
      console.log(element);
    },
  }
});
```

In my console, I get the object referring to the whole document rather than referring to the input tag that the checkbox is sourcing the event from.

I'm sure I have the code wrong, but I can't seem to find my answer in similar questions that are asking for the code in pure Javascript in. Could someone help me here? Thank you.

Comment: is it something to do with if i use 'this' in a form element, it passes on the object of the whole form element rather than just the input checkbox i'm trying to reference from?

Comment: What do you want to do with the element? Typically there are other ways to accomplish what you want to do in Vue.

Comment: i need to give new class to an element in the same container div. I should probably place the code in the component containing the element, but my hands are full...

Comment: Vue is data driven. The classes for whatever other element should be driven by data. The second approach @thanksd mentions below is closer to ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `this` from the context of an inline statement in the Vue instance's template is going to pass a reference to [the `Window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

If you want to access an element from a method in your Vue instance, you can use a `ref`. No need to pass anything.

[Here's the documentation on the `ref` attribute.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    addGreenClass() {
      console.log(this.$refs.input)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input ref="input" @click="addGreenClass"> 
</div>
```

---

If you're trying to add a class to the element, you don't need to reference the element at all in your `addGreenClass` method. Simply bind an array of class names (say `inputClasses`) to your input using `:class="inputClasses"`, and then push the name of the class you want to the array in your `addGreenClass` method. Vue will update the DOM automatically:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputClasses: ['large'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addGreenClass() {
      this.inputClasses.push('green');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.large { 
  height: 40px;
}

.green {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input :class="inputClasses" @click="addGreenClass"> 
</div>
```

Comment: o, i'm trying that now :) sorry, my vue.js skills are poor. :)

Comment: you are a godsend!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using checkboxes, I'm stealing a little code from @thanksd and showing how it might be done without even using a method. This highlights Vue's data driven approach.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      classes: [],
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.large { 
  height: 40px;
}

.green {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :class="classes">Styled DIV</div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="green" v-model="classes"> 
    Green
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="large" v-model="classes"> 
    Large
  </label>
  
</div>
```